# Casting objects that do not have a relationship

Tags: java, casting

Sorry if this question is too specific but I can't seem to think of the right terminology to explain it in an abstract way.

I have two classes for the same entity. One for saving it to the database

```
public class XDb extends SugarRecord {

    private float ampX;
    private float ampY;
}
```

and the other for Api calls:

```
public class XApi extends ApiFunctionality {

    private float ampX;
    private float ampY;
}
```

I first save the objects in the local database, then I read from the database and upload data to the server.
I want to be able to do something like this:

```
XApi xApi = (XApi) xDb;
```

Is there any functionality in java that supports this?
Apologies if I am still ambiguous.

Comment: What is `xDb` variable? Do you want cast `XDb` to `XApi`? Not, it isn't possible in any way.

Comment: You can't cast them, you can map them, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast them, since the types are unrelated.

Assuming that you have:

- Appropriate accessors (e.g. `getAmpX()` and `getAmpY()`, or non-private visibility of `ampX` and `ampY` - not recommended) on the class that you want to convert *from* (`XDb` in your example);
- An appropriate constructor on the class that you want to convert *to* (`XApi` in your example)

then you can simply construct an instance of the latter using the properties of the former:

```
XApi xApi = new XApi(xDb.getAmpX(), xDb.getAmpY());
```

Comment: I guess this would have to do. Though I am not very happy.

Comment: @Usmankhan if you are writing this once, write it once and move on; if you are having to write this many times, write a utility function to allow you to reuse the same logic.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no. You can't. They have to have some relationship. They could both implement a common interface, for example.

Answer (score 1):

They must be of the same hierarchy tree,
if XApi inherits (extends) XDb, you will be able to cast.

Comment: XDb inherits from SugarRecord functionality related to the data storage, and XApi inherits from ApiFunctionality that has api calling related functionality.
What do you think would be a correct way of designing the application?

Comment: The correct design must not involve trying to cast classes that are not related in any way, maybe you should ask yourself, why do I need to cast those in the first place?

Comment: I feel like within my application these models have similarities that I should be able to represent in the code. I can just define a function xApifromXDb() but I don't feel it would be the right approach. (In Scala, we can specify converters in companion objects which can perform casting, In python/Django, we have serializers) Isn't there a better way than that?